# How to implement this Traversable use pattern?

Tags: haskell, traversal, applicative

When use `Data.Traversable` I frequently requires some code like

```
import Control.Applicative (Applicative,(<*>),pure)
import Data.Traversable (Traversable,traverse,sequenceA)
import Control.Monad.State (state,runState)

traverseF :: Traversable t => ((a,s) -> (b,s)) -> (t a, s) -> (t b, s)
traverseF f (t,s) = runState (traverse (state.curry f) t) s
```

to traverse the structure and build up a new one driven by some state. And I notice the type signature pattern and believe it could be able to generalized as

```
fmapInner :: (Applicative f,Traversable t) => (f a -> f b) -> f (t a) -> f (t b)
fmapInner f t = ???
```

But I fail to implement this with just `traverse`,  `sequenceA`, `fmap`, `<*>` and `pure`. Maybe I need stronger type class constrain? Do I absolutely need a `Monad` here?

**UPDATE**

Specifically, I want to know if I can define `fmapInner` for a `f` that work for any `Traversable t` and some laws for intuition applied (I don't know what the laws should be yet), is it imply that the `f` thing is a `Monad`? Since, for `Monad`s the implementation is trivial:

```
--Monad m implies Applicative m but we still 
--  have to say it unless we use mapM instead
fmapInner :: (Monad m,Traversable t) => (m a -> m b) -> m (t a) -> m (t b)
fmapInner f t = t >>= Data.Traversable.mapM (\a -> f (return a))
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the excellent answer. I have found that my `traverseF` is just

```
import Data.Traversable (mapAccumL)
traverseF1 :: Traversable t => ((a, b) -> (a, c)) -> (a, t b) -> (a, t c)
traverseF1 =uncurry.mapAccumL.curry
```

without using Monad.State explicitly and have all pairs flipped. Previously I though it was `mapAccumR` but it is actually `mapAccumL` that works like `traverseF`.

Comment: The type you're asking for in `fmapInner` looks substantially different from the type of `traverseF` to me. Perhaps you would prefer `foo :: (a -> f b) -> (t a -> f (t b))` or some such thing, in which case it's just `traverse`. Then `f` can specialize to `State s` and give you essentially the type of `traverseF`.

Comment: On rereading, I've just convinced myself that I don't really understand what you're asking for. So feel free to ignore my previous comment, but I'll leave it for posterity anyway.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I see the thing you have just pointed out. I already know that I can write the function like yours; However, in my opinion it looks natural to define a reusable function `f a -> f b` and then use it to convert a `f (t a)` into `f (t b)`, and it looks like there is no good way to do so unless I assume `f` is a `Monad`.

Comment: What do you imagine the `Applicative` instance for `((,) s)` is (we have to put `s` first since we don't have `flip` defined for types)?

Comment: I am not saying `((,) s)` is currently an instance of `Applicative`, but if you want we can define a `newtype` to instantiate it. The point is about the type signature pattern, not the specific types.

Comment: In an `Applicative` instance for `((,) s)`, what value would be put in the second slot of the tuple for `pure`? What would `<*>` do with two values of type `s` when it combines a tuple containing a function and an `s` with a tuple containing an argument and an `s`. There is an instance `Monoid a => ((,) a)` that uses `mempty` and `mappend` respectively. There's no `Applicative f => f a` that's analogous to `(a, s)`, so I don't see the type signatures of traverseF and fmapInner as being analogous.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain this must be a monad. Specifically, you're types suggest that any reasonable implementation is going to have the type `f (f (t b))` for which you need `join`.

Comment: It boils down to why you can't write a `traverseF :: Applicative f, Traversable t, (a -> f b) -> f (t a) -> f (t b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now convinced myself that this is impossible. Here's why,

```
 tF ::(Applicative f, Traversable t) => (f a -> f b) -> f (t a) -> f (t b)
```

So we have this side-effecting computation that returns `t a` and we want to use this to determine what side effects happen. In other words, the value of type `t a` will determine what side effects happen when we apply `traverse`.

However this isn't possible possible with the applicative type class. We can dynamically choose values, but the side effects of out computations are static. To see what I mean,

```
pure :: a -> f a -- No side effects
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b -- The side effects of `f a` can't
                                  -- decide based on `f (a -> b)`.
```

Now there are two conceivable ways to determine side effects at depending on previous values,

```
smash :: f (f a) -> f a
```

Because then we can simply do

```
smash $ (f :: a -> f a) <$> (fa :: f a) :: f a
```

Now your function becomes

```
traverseF f t = smash $ traverse (f . pure) <$> t
```

Or we can have

```
bind :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b -- and it's obvious how `a -> m b`
                                 -- can choose side effects.
```

and

```
traverseF f t = bind t (traverse $ f . pure)
```

But these are `join` and `>>=` respectively and are members of the `Monad` typeclass. So yes, you need a monad. :(

Also, a nice, pointfree implementation of your function with monad constraints is

```
traverseM = (=<<) . mapM . (.return)
```

#### Edit,

I suppose it's worth noting that

```
traverseF :: (Applicative f,Traversable t) => (f a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t a)
traverseF = traverse . (.pure)
```

Comment: I have tried to follow your comments on `pure`, `<*>` and `bind`, but I don't think I understand them well. Can you gives more explain them a bit more?